# Find Hexadecimal colors in array

Tags: javascript, regex

I am creating an expression regular to find Hexadecimal colors inside of a string in an array and push it to a new array.
I was able to create it but I would like **do not** push if it comes from an SVG property like `fill: #fff` or `fill=\"#298dcd`.
Any idea how to exclude if matches with the properties above?

```js
const myArray = ["font-family: Roboto;\n\n    @media ${sm} {\n        background-color: #000;","height: 30px;\n    object-fit: contain;\n    margin-bottom: 6px;\n    fill: #fff;", "<g\n                className={fillableCn}\n                transform=\"translate(-284.000000, -181.000000)\"\n                fill=\"#298dcd\"\n            >"]

const findHex = () => {
  let colorReg = /#[a-fA-F0-9]{6}|#[a-fA-F0-9]{3}/g;
  let colors = [];

  myArray.map((str) => {
    let strUpperCase = str.toUpperCase();
    while ((match = colorReg.exec(strUpperCase)) !== null) {
      if (colors.includes(match[0])) {
        console.log("repeatedColors");
      } else {
        colors.push(match[0]);
      }
    }
  });

  console.log("-----------------");
  console.log(colors);
  console.log("Number of colors: ", colors.length);
  console.log("-----------------");
};

findHex()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(?<!fill(: |=\\"))#[a-fA-F0-9]{3,6}
```

Explanation is [here](https://regex101.com/r/0MlxvQ/1)

**EDIT**
right regex for your code (you made upper string)

```
(?<!fill(: |=\"))#[a-f0-9]{3,6}/gi
```

or (it depends of engine)

```
(?<!fill(: |=\\"))#[a-f0-9]{3,6}/gi
```

Copy-paste:
Negative Lookbehind `(?<!fill(: |=\"))`

Assert that the Regex below does not match

fill matches the characters fill literally (case sensitive)

1st Capturing Group `(: |=\")`

1st Alternative :

`:`  matches the characters :  literally (case sensitive)

2nd Alternative `=\"`

`=` matches the character `=` with index 6110 (3D16 or 758) literally (case sensitive)

`\` matches the character `\` with index 9210 (5C16 or 1348) literally (case sensitive)

`"` matches the character `"` with index 3410 (2216 or 428) literally (case sensitive)

`#` matches the character `#` with index 3510 (2316 or 438) literally (case sensitive)

Match a single character present in the list below `[a-fA-F0-9]`

`{3,6}` matches the previous token between 3 to 6 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

`a-f` matches a single character in the range between a (index 97) and f (index 102) (case sensitive)

`A-F` matches a single character in the range between A (index 65) and F (index 70) (case sensitive)

`0-9` matches a single character in the range between 0 (index 48) and 9 (index 57) (case sensitive)

```js
const myArray = ["font-family: Roboto;\n\n    @media ${sm} {\n        background-color: #000;","height: 30px;\n    object-fit: contain;\n    margin-bottom: 6px;\n    fill: #fff;", "<g\n                className={fillableCn}\n                transform=\"translate(-284.000000, -181.000000)\"\n                fill=\"#298dcd\"\n            >"]

const findHex = () => {
  let colorReg = /(?<!fill(: |=\"))#[a-f0-9]{3,6}/gi;
  let colors = [];

  myArray.map((str) => {
    let strUpperCase = str.toUpperCase();
    while ((match = colorReg.exec(strUpperCase)) !== null) {
      if (colors.includes(match[0])) {
        console.log("repeatedColors");
      } else {
        colors.push(match[0]);
      }
    }
  });

  console.log("-----------------");
  console.log(colors);
  console.log("Number of colors: ", colors.length);
  console.log("-----------------");
};

findHex()
```

Comment: The explanation is very good but I replace the colorRegex variable for `let colorReg = /(?<!fill(: |=\\"))#[a-fA-F0-9]{3,}/gm;` and the array keep printing with the hexadecimal color from fill property .

Comment: I tried to use with {3,6} but keep print the array 3 color and should print only one.
```
-----------------
[ '#000', '#FFF', '#298DCD' ]
Number of colors:  3
-----------------
```

Comment: @MarioRodeghiero I've edited my answer check "(?<!fill(: |=\"))#[a-fA-F0-9]{3,6}/gmi"                                             "{3,6} matches the previous token between 3 and unlimited times" - no, it doesn't. - it's true, it's artefacts after edit ;)

Comment: If you are using the `i` flag you don't need `a-f` and `A-F`. Also, you don't need the `m` flag as you are not using `^` or `$`.

Comment: Right thats still artefacts - hurry :) Edit is made.

Comment: Thanks @PowiadamCię it works properly, much better 

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the use-case you might get away with using a negative lookbehind:

```
(?<!fill=\\\")(?<!fill: )((#[a-fA-F0-9]{6})|(#[a-fA-F0-9]{3}))
```

Be aware that it is not widely supported though.
https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind

Comment: good that you mentioned that the lookbehind is not widely supported. **No Safari support at all** (iPhone / Mac), which is critical.

Comment: I tried to replace let colorReg variable for your regex but didn't work for me.